# A condition for both cyclic and tangential quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

I'm looking for a nice condition that characterizes quadrilaterals that are both cyclic and tangential (i.e. there exists a circle that touches each side).

I know that both concepts have some nice properties, but I try to put them into one "nice" condition. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Characterizations

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have a characterization such that the quadrilateral is cyclic AND tangential at the same time.

Comment: Such a thing is called bicentric quadrilateral. Read more here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral :)